# Number of ways to fill a n*m piece matrix with L-shaped three piece tiles using recursive programming

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix

I'm looking for an approach to this problem where you have to fill a n*m (n, m <=8) piece matrix with L-shaped three piece tiles. The tiles can't be placed on top of each other in any way.

I'm not necessarily looking for the whole answer, just a hint on how to approach it.

Source: https://cses.fi/dt/task/336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this [graph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) using a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm plus [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). My solution is not particularly fast and takes a minute or so to solve a 9x12 grid, but it should be sufficient for the 8x8 grid in your question (it takes about a second on a 9x9). There are no solutions for 7x7 and 8x8 grids because they are not divisible by the triomino size, 3.

The strategy is to start in a corner of the grid and move through it cell by cell, trying to place each block whenever it is legal to do so and thereby exploring the solution space methodically.

If placement of a block is legal but creates an unfillable air pocket in the grid, remove the block; we know ahead of time there will be no solutions to this state and can abandon exploring its children. For example, on a 3x6 grid,

```
abb.c.
aabcc.
......
```

is hopelessly unsolvable.

Once a state is reached where all cells have been filled, we can report a count of 1 solution to its parent state. Here's an example of a solved 3x6 grid:

```
aaccee
abcdef
bbddff
```

If every possible block has been placed at a position, backtrack, reporting the solution count to parent states along the way and exploring any states that are as yet unexplored.

In terms of memoization, call any two grid states equivalent if there is some arrangement of tiles such that they cover the exact same coordinates. For example:

```
aacc..
abdc..
bbdd..
```

and

```
aacc..
bacd..
bbdd..
```

are considered to be equivalent even though the two states were reached through different tile placements. Both states have the same substructure, so counting the number of solutions to one state is enough; add this to the memo, and if we reach the state again, we can simply report the number of solutions from the memo rather than re-computing everything.

My program reports 8 solutions on a 3x6 grid:

[image: tiling sample run]

As I mentioned, my Python solution isn't fast or optimized. It's possible to solve a 9x12 grid less than a second. Large optimizations aside, there are basic things I neglected in my implementation. For example, I copied the entire grid for each tile placement; adding/removing tiles on a single grid would have been an easy improvement. I also did not check for unsolvable gaps in the grid, which can be seen in the animation.

After you solve the the problem, be sure to hunt around for some of the mind-blowing solutions people have come up with. I don't want to give away much more than this!

Comment: Don't want to give more than this! So, have more than stated above?

Comment: @jiten OP's question asks "I'm not necessarily looking for the whole answer, just a hint on how to approach it." so I didn't provide complete code, only a high-level algorithm. Search for walkthroughs/hints/solutions to [Project Euler 161](https://projecteuler.net/problem=161) or [CSES: Filling Trominos](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/2423) if you need more info for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick that's applicable to a lot of recursive enumeration problems. In whichever way you like, define a deterministic procedure for removing one piece from a nonempty partial solution. Then the recursive enumeration works in the opposite direction, building the possible solutions from the empty solution, but each time it places a piece, that same piece has to be the one that would be removed by the deterministic procedure.

If you verify that the board size is divisible by three before beginning the enumeration, you shouldn't have any problem with the time limit.

Comment: Do you have more details on this method? Sounds interesting

Comment: @ThomasAhle ISOMORPH-FREE EXHAUSTIVE GENERATION
Brendan D. McKay: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8c3b/0ff6b5b410f9af07b0c94e0f40ed0bbab855.pdf